# updating data in codiegniter with out selecting the file field in form

Tags: codeigniter

I am updating the data in database where I have images file too .So what i want is to put the condition on the image input field if the user want to update data as well as the image so the image will be updated accordingly and if user don't want to update image the rest of the data will be updated now I am having problem in getting the image input field data in controller. I am unable to get the filename directly in controller please help me out.
Here is the code.

```
function save_update()
    {
         $id=$this->input->post('id');

        if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
        {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['max_width']  = '2000';
        $config['max_height']  = '2000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_successful', $error);
        }
        else
        {

                $data1 = $this->upload->data();
                $filename=$data1['file_name'];

        $data=array(
        'pname'=>$this->input->post('product_name'),
        'pprice'=>$this->input->post('product_price'),
        'pquantity'=>$this->input->post('product_quantity'),
        'pcategory'=>$this->input->post('category'),
        'product_pic'=>$filename
        );
      $result=$this->cartmodel->update_data($data,$id,'product');
        }
      }

     else
     {
        $data=array(
        'pname'=>$this->input->post('product_name'),
        'pprice'=>$this->input->post('product_price'),
        'pquantity'=>$this->input->post('product_quantity'),
        'pcategory'=>$this->input->post('category'),
        'product_pic'=>$this->input->post('oldfile')
        );
      $result=$this->cartmodel->update_data($data,$id,'product');
      if($result==true)
      {
          redirect('cart/admin');
      }
      else
      {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("sorry Could\'nt delete the file")</script>';
      }

     }

    }
```

Html is here.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart/save_update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($specific))
                    {?> 
                                  <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Form Components</legend>
                                     <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="project_tittle">Product Name</label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" class="span6" id="typeahead"  name="product_name" value=
                                        "<?=$specific->pname;   ?>">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$specific->pid ?>">
                                   <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="project_name">Price </label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" class="span6" id="typeahead"  name="product_price" 
                                        value=
                                        "<?=$specific->pprice;   ?>">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="project_caption">Quantity </label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="number" class="span6" id="typeahead"  name="product_quantity"
                                        value=
                                        "<?=$specific->pquantity;   ?>">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="project_link">Category </label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <select name="category">
                                        <option value=
                                        "<?=$specific->pcategory;   ?>"><?=$specific->pcategory;   ?></option>

                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <label class="control-label" for="userfile">Product Pic </label>
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="file" class="span6" id="typeahead"  name="userfile" >
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                   <input type="hidden" name="oldfile" value="<?=$specific->product_pic;   ?>" >
                                    <div class="form-actions">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                      <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>


                                  </fieldset>
                                         <?php
                }
                    ?>
                                </form>
```

Comment: You are loading the upload library too late, it needs to be placed before you set any of the config data

Comment: dear only tell me how can I get the image input field data

Comment: check my condition is it correct to get name of image input field

Comment: yes, thats correct, you are not getting the image name? is the file uploaded? have you checked?

Comment: Try `print_r($data1)` in your if statement and see what data is being shown

Comment: if(!empty($_FILES['username']['name']) is a check for weather user have select the file if yes than upload this one if no the upload the rest of data without updating the image

Comment: the problem is with this condtion dear if(!empty($_FILES['username']['name'])

Comment: if condition is not working else condtion is working fine

Comment: $_FILES['username']['name'] I have also checked this with echo but it does not show anything

Comment: Where is `if(!empty($_FILES['username']['name'])` in your code?? Instead of `if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))`, try `if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))`

Comment: If I put this an an answer will you accept it, so people know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
```

With

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))
```

It is best practice to use isset() to see whether the data is being set or not

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())

With

> if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['userfile']['name']))